# Изменить href ссылки при клике на таб

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Приветствую.

Имеется блок с табами и ссылка для перехода, нужно при клике таба менять href ссылки через jquery. Заранее благодарен!

Код

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="st-left">
        <div class="st-tabs">
            <span class="active" >TAB1</span>
            <span>TAB2</span>
            <span>TAB3</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="st-right" href="/test1.html">Еще<span class="fa fa-align-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например вот. При клике на "таб" ссылка меняется.

```js
var link = $(".st-right");
$(".st-tabs").on("click", "span", function() {
  link.attr("href", "http://www.ya.ru/");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="st-left">
    <div class="st-tabs">
      <span class="active">TAB1</span>
      <span>TAB2</span>
      <span>TAB3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <a class="st-right" href="/test1.html">Еще<span class="fa fa-align-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

Скорей всего, вам потребуется чтоб у каждого *"таба"*, была своя ссылка. В таком случаи можно хранить её в `data-атрибуте`, и подставлять при клике:

```js
var link = $(".st-right");
$(".st-tabs").on("click", "span", function(){
  link.attr("href", $(this).data("url"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
    <div class="st-left">
        <div class="st-tabs">
            <span class="active" data-url="https://www.ya.ru/">TAB1</span>
            <span data-url="https://www.google.com/">TAB2</span>
            <span data-url="https://www.site.ru/">TAB3</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <a class="st-right" href="/test1.html">Еще<span class="fa fa-align-right"></span></a>
</div>
```